# EF CodeFirst computed field in CF entity class

Tags: linq, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have added computed fields(`Active` and `CreditsLeft`) directly into my CodeFirst entity class. Is it good idea to add computed field logic inside CF Entity class?

```
 public class User : Entity
    {
        public User()
        {
            Id = Helper.GetRandomInt(9);
            DateStamp = DateTime.UtcNow;
            TimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.Utc.Id;
        }

        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int Id { get; set; }               
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string Password { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public DateTime DateStamp { get; set; }        

        public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Statistic> Statistics { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Notification> Notifications { get; set; }


        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
        public bool Active
        {
            get
            {
                return Orders.Any(c => c.Active && (c.TransactionType == TransactionType.Order || c.TransactionType == TransactionType.Subscription));
            }
        }

        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
        public int CreditsLeft
        {
            get
            {
                return Orders.Sum(p => p.Credits != null ? p.Credits.Value : 0);
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it good idea to add computed field logic inside CF Entity class?

Sure, you can do this, but there are a few things you must take care of.

First, the attribute for a property that is computed by business logic is not `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]`, because this indicates that the value is computed in the database (as in a computed column). You should mark the property by the `[NotMapped]` attribute. This tells Entity Framework to ignore the property in database mapping.

Second, since both properties use `Orders`, you must make sure that the orders are loaded or can be lazy loaded when either property is accessed. So you may want to load `User`s with an `Include` statement (`Include(user => user.Orders)`). Or else you must ensure that the context is still alive when `Active` or `CreditsLeft` is accessed.

Third, you can't address the properties directly in an EF LINQ query, as in

```
db.Users.Select(u => u.Active);
```

because EF will throw an exception that it doesn't know `Active`. You can address the properties only on materialized user objects in memory.